# How do you want to change the hover color to have multiple colors?

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I want to make when hover button first time have white label but when click on button to close it will turn gray but label still hover white. which i can't find for this sovle

```
.p-button:hover {
  .p-button-label {
    color: #ffffff !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: please rephrase your question and add your HTML code

Comment: please explain what are you trying to close

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not(:active)`, see [about not](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [about active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

```
.p-button:hover:not(:active){
  .p-button-label {
    color: #ffffff !important;
  }
}
```

But you should avoid use "!important", try makes more specific your button

```
 <p-button class="custom" label="Submit"></p-button>
```

And use:

```
.custom .p-button:hover:not(:active){
    .p-button-label {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
  }
```